Error 404 when inserting data into a table in google bigquery via nodeJs
I am trying to create and insert data into a table in google bigquery via nodeJs. When I run the script it gives me 404 error in the very first execution. But from 2 nd execution onwards it returns me the output. Do you have any suggestions to overcome this issue? Thank you
public async insertData(bigquery: BigQuery, rows: any[], datasetName: string, tableName: string, schema: string) {
        try {
      
          // Check if the dataset exists, and create if it doesn't
          const datasetExists = await  bigquery.dataset(datasetName).exists()
      
          if (!datasetExists[0]) {
            console.log(`Dataset ${datasetName} not found. Creating dataset...`)
            await bigquery.createDataset(datasetName, { location: 'US' })
          }
      
          // Check if the table exists, and create if it doesn't
          const tableExists = await bigquery.dataset(datasetName).table(tableName).exists()
          if (!tableExists[0]) {
            console.log(`Table ${tableName} not found. Creating table...`)
             await bigquery.dataset(datasetName).createTable(tableName, { schema })
            
          }


      
          // Insert rows into the table
         
          const table = bigquery.dataset(datasetName).table(tableName)
           table.get()
          if (rows && rows.length > 0 ) {
            const insertResponse = await table.insert(rows)
            console.log('Inserted rows:', insertResponse, tableName)
          }
         
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error:', error)
        }
      }


Can you please post a complete error message? Given that you have multiple calls to BigQuery in here, it would be helpful to see exactly where the 404 is occurring.
